# C# string manipulation, why this doesn't work?

Tags: c#

```
int i = 1;
for (; i <= 10; i++)
{
    string str = "test{0}" , i;
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

So this code doesn't work, and I want to know the reason, and what are correct ways to produce this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: What is the output you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why doesn't `1, 2` compile? Same thing here.

Comment: You should have mentioned that your language of choice is Python then your syntax errors would have made more sense quicker to persons familiar with both C# and Python.

Comment: An argument list is not an *expression*. That is "M(a,b)" is not the same thing as "x=a,b;M(x)" An argument list has to go in a position where arguments are expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you meant to wrap that with a String.Format call.

```
string str = String.Format("test{0}", i);
```

Answer (score 6):

You should try this syntax:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {     
    string str = String.Format("test{0}", i);
    Console.WriteLine(str); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you have defined your string doesn't look correct to me at all. I'm guessing the code you're looking for is:

```
int i = 1;
for(; i <= 10; i++)
{
    string str = string.Format("test{0}", i);
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

But in that case there's really no reason to create a new string and call `Format()` for every iteration. You can create a single string and let `Console.WriteLine()` handle the formating.

```
string str = "test{0}";

for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(str, i);
```

Comment: Ew, no curly braces. Just bothers me for probably very little reason.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you want something like this:

```
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("test{0}",i);
```

You can put any number of things in brackets, separate each input with a comma.

```
string Month = "Jan";
int day = 21;
string temp = String.Format("Today is:{0} - {1}/{2}",Month,day,2011);
```

temp gets the value "Today is:Jan - 21/2011"

In the future the desired output would be helpful.

Edit: spelling

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;  
for (; i <= 10; i++)  Console.WriteLine("test{0}", i);
```